# PDF and CDF in joint probability distribution

Tags: probability, integration, probability-distributions

In case of joint probabiility distribution of $X$ and $Y$, if we define $F(x,y) = \mathbb P(X \le x, Y \le y) = x + y$ for $x, y \in [0,0.5]$, $1$ for $x,y > 0.5$ and $0$ elsewhere, then the joint probability distribution function $f(x,y)$ will be $0$ everywhere (defined as the mixed derivative over both $x$ and $y$). However the integral of $f(x,y)$ can't be 0, it should be equal to 1 over the whole range of $x$ and $y$, especially knowing that the CDF is not zero.
What am I missing here?

Comment: Is $F(x,y) = \mathbb P(X \le x, Y \le y)$?  If so it is not $0$ everywhere elsewhere

Comment: Sorry, yes, I mean 1 for x, y > 0.5 and 0 elsewhere.

Comment: I suspect you mean $F(x,y) = \min\left(\max(x,0),\frac12\right) + \min\left(\max(y,0),\frac12\right)$

Comment: Correct, I wasn't very precise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not every distribution function has a density (w.r.t. Lebesgue measure). In this case, suppose $(X,Y)$ had distribution function $F$. Then $P(X= 0)=P(X\leq 0, Y \leq 0.5)=\frac 1 2$. This implies that $X$ has no density function. Neither does $(X,Y)$.

Comment: Could you explain why $P(X= 0)=P(X\leq 0, Y \leq 0.5)$ and why is it equal to 0.5?

Comment: Both random variables take values in $[0,0.5]$. Hence $P(X \leq 0, Y\leq 0.5)=P(X \leq 0)=P(X=0)$. ($X=0$ is same as $X \leq 0$ because $X \geq 0$). Finally  $P(X \leq 0, Y\leq 0.5)=F(0,0.5)=0+0.5=0.5$.

Comment: Thanks, and the density function doesn't exist because the derivative of the CDF is zero, but we know that the integral has to be 1? Or what is the correct explanation here?

Comment: Well, there are many ways of showing that density does not exist and your method is one. Showing that the density is $0$ is a  valid proof. What I have done is to show that $X$ and $Y$ are not continuous random variables. For a continuous random variable $X$ we must have $P(X=x)=0$ for every $x$.